# XML tree - extract the subtags values only if the main tag has a certain property value

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am new to XML and working on the parser, let me first illustrate my problem:

```
<animals>
      <pet type="dog">
        <name>Jack</name>
        <name>Benny</name>
        <name>Will</name>
      </pet>
      <pet type="cat">
        <name>Luna</name>
        <name>Lilith</name>
        <name>Willow</name>
      </pet>
      <pet type="rabbit">
        <name>Lilly</name>
        <name>Robin</name>
      </pet>
</animals>
```

From this tree I would like to extract only the names of dogs (Jack, Benny, Will).
I've tried:

```
name = file.getElementsByTagName('name')
pets = file.getElementsByTagName('pet')
for i in pets:
    if (i.attributes['type'].value == "dog"):
            for j in name: 
               print(j.firstChild.data)
```

I am getting all names as I am using the whole subset of pets. My question is how to indicate that I want to explicitly select the tag  and loop through it to get only the 3 names.
I would like to stick to xml.dom.minidom and not use the Element Tree.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```py
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString

xml_string = '''
<animals>
      <pet type="dog">
        <name>Jack</name>
        <name>Benny</name>
        <name>Will</name>
      </pet>
      <pet type="cat">
        <name>Luna</name>
        <name>Lilith</name>
        <name>Willow</name>
      </pet>
      <pet type="rabbit">
        <name>Lilly</name>
        <name>Robin</name>
      </pet>
</animals>
'''

root = parseString(xml_string)

for pet in root.getElementsByTagName('pet'):    
    if pet.attributes['type'].value == 'dog':
        names = pet.getElementsByTagName('name')
        print([name.firstChild.data for name in names])
```

Output:

```
['Jack', 'Benny', 'Will']
```